# reactstrap List.name='List' error in gatsby while building

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, bootstrap-5, netlify, reactstrap

[image]

gatsby build is always failing on this line `List.name='List'` of reactstrap. I tried different solutions but not helpful.

**- reactstrap version 9.0.1**
**- gatsby version ^3.14.4**
**- bootstrap version 5**

Comment: What solutions have you tried? Is the assignment of `List.name="List"` something in your code or it comes from the library?

Comment: it's come from reactstrap library

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a null loader to bypass SSR?

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions, loaders, getConfig }) => {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /reactstrap/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
}
```

Change `reactstrap` for the exact folder name in `node_modules`.